# Comparing DateTime.Date in CosmosDB SQL Api using Cosmonaut

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I've run into a rather peculiar problem with CosmosDB using the SQL Api.

I basically have an entity that has a CreatedAt field, which is stored in the iso format, e.g:

```
{
    "CreatedAt": "2019-06-05T10:55:19.3265682Z"
}
```

It is on an entity modelled as a DateTime:

```
public class MyEntity {

    DateTime CreatedAt {get;set;} = DateTime.UtcNow;

}
```

If I try to do a simple compare with today, it simply retrieves 0 values:

```
_store.Query().Where(x => x.CreatedAt.Date == DateTime.UtcNow).ToListAsync();
```

I tried this:

```
var test = await _store.Query().FirstOrDefaultAsync(); // 1 item

var f = test.CreatedAt.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date; // True

var offers = await _store.Query().Where(x => x.CreatedAt.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date ).ToListAsync(); // 0 results
```

To me it looks like the Linq clause evaluates to a non-iso format, although it's weird because the Json.Net serializer defaults to the ISO standard, which is what is saved in Cosmos.

The SQL created is:

```
{"query":"SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE ((root[\"CosmosEntityName\"] = \"offers\") AND (root[\"CreatedAt\"][\"Date\"] = \"2019-06-05T00:00:00Z\")) "}
```

Which looks right from a parsing perspective, but it sure looks like it translates x.CreatedAt.Date to a nested property, especially because it tries to access it as ["CreatedAt"]["Date"].

If I omit the `.Date` it obviously compares something like `2019-06-05T12:26:43.0025189Z = 2019-06-05T00:00:00Z` which is of course not truthy.

Running that query in the emulator also yields a result that makes no sense:

```
SELECT root["CreatedAt"]["Date"]  FROM root WHERE root["CosmosEntityName"] = "offers" 
->
[
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
...
]
```

Looking at the documentation there is an example that looks like this:

```
IQueryable<Order> orders = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Order>("/dbs/orderdb/colls/orders")
    .Where(o => o.ShipDate >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-3));
```

Which leads me to think if I should simply ignore comparing actual Dates (or store them in their own separate property?) and just use `>=` and `<=` to wrap everything around the actual timestamp, that just seems silly.

Comment: Worth pointing out that Cosmonaut doesn't manipulate the default JsonSerializer or the LINQ to SQL query generation in any way. Your issue is applicable to the v2 SDK as well.

Comment: Using `CreatedAt.Date` makes the LINQ to SQL translator to think that it's a nested object inside the class. That's how the underlying v2 SDK is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CreatedAt.Date` makes the LINQ to SQL translator to think that it's a nested object inside the class.

If you need to do just Date comparisons in your `CreatedAt` properly then the simplest way to do that is to store both the `CreatedAt` as `DateTime` and the `CreateAtDate` which is the same `CreatedAt` `DateTime` with the Time part set to 0.

Then simply do:

```
var offers = await _store.Query().Where(x => x.CreatedAtDate == DateTime.UtcNow.Date ).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: That was exactly what I ended up doing.

Comment: Any update here?